# Ionic + PouchDB + Sqlite not working, with build warnings

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I followed the tutorial referenced on the [pouchDB site](http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html). But I am consistently getting `sqlite_plugin: false` whenever testing my app on the simulator.

When I removed the ios platform and re-added it, and ran through my `ionic build ios`, I am getting several build warnings. I've searched around but couldn't find any more information about these:

`/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/sqlite3.c:32015:9: warning: 'gethostuuid' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 5.0 - gethostuuid() is no longer supported [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    if( gethostuuid(pHostID, &timeout) ){
        ^
/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/sqlite3.c:32003:12: note: 'gethostuuid' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
extern int gethostuuid(uuid_t id, const struct timespec *wait);
           ^
/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/sqlite3.c:8970:26: warning: unused variable 'sqlite3one' [-Wunused-const-variable]
SQLITE_PRIVATE const int sqlite3one = 1;
                         ^
/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/sqlite3.c:12934:21: warning: unused function 'sqlite3BenignMallocHooks' [-Wunused-function]
SQLITE_PRIVATE void sqlite3BenignMallocHooks(void (*)(void), void (*)(void));
                    ^
/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/sqlite3.c:13083:20: warning: unused function 'sqlite3BitvecBuiltinTest' [-Wunused-function]
SQLITE_PRIVATE int sqlite3BitvecBuiltinTest(int,int*);
                   ^
/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/sqlite3.c:13187:21: warning: unused function 'sqlite3PrngSaveState' [-Wunused-function]
SQLITE_PRIVATE void sqlite3PrngSaveState(void);
                    ^
/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/sqlite3.c:13188:21: warning: unused function 'sqlite3PrngRestoreState' [-Wunused-function]
SQLITE_PRIVATE void sqlite3PrngRestoreState(void);
                    ^
6 warnings generated.`

**as well as later on:**
`/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/SQLitePlugin.m:47:17: warning: method definition for 'getBlobAsBase64String:withlength:' not found [-Wincomplete-implementation]
@implementation SQLitePlugin
                ^
In file included from /Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/SQLitePlugin.m:9:
/Users/Milkmusket/Documents/tarot/platforms/ios/Golden Thread Tarot/Plugins/io.litehelpers.cordova.sqliteStorage/SQLitePlugin.h:55:1: note: method 'getBlobAsBase64String:withlength:' declared here
+(NSString*)getBlobAsBase64String:(const char*) blob_chars
^
1 warning generated.`

The kicker is that it apparently works on another person's computer who is helping me test. Pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Thanks in advance.